# load node_type_form form

Tags: 7, forms

I need to load and print drupal 'internal' form on the page, which id is "node_type_form"
I have:

`$form = drupal_get_form("node_type_form");`

`$html = drupal_render($form);`

`echo $html;`

it only prints "Menu settings" and "Save and add fields" button.

I get:

`Notice: Undefined index: node_type_form in drupal_retrieve_form()`

`Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'node_type_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form()`

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in menu_form_node_type_form_alter()`
`Notice: Undefined index: #node_type in menu_form_node_type_form_alter()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node_type_form()` lives in modules/node/content_types.inc, which the system only includes when it needs to (to fulfil menu paths etc).

If you include it manually before your call to `drupal_get_form()` it should work...

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'content_types');
$form = drupal_get_form("node_type_form");
// ...
```

Comment: I should have noticed that when I was looking at the API. worked great! thanks